# Angular Material MatDatePicker showing '100' instead of '2000' in years

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker, angular-material

I'm using a Mat Datepicker in my form but I'm facing a strange issue, all the years after 1999 start at 100 as you see on the screen. My HTML code is the same as the example and I added a formControlName and an ID that seem to cause the issue. I printed `field.id` for you to see and it's equal to `retroactiveDate`

i'd like to have the normal years shown here, what am I doing wrong ?

Thank you

```
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'date'" fxLayout="row">
    {{field.id}}
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="datePicker" [formControlName]="field.id" [id]="field.id" [placeholder]="field.placeholder"
    />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #datePicker></mat-datepicker>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: What is the result for consoling `field.id`?

Comment: `retroactiveDate`

Comment: I think it's because of two way data binding. remove this and see `[formControlName]="field.id"`

Comment: share you ts code what is the structure of your `formGroup`

Comment: Quick update, it's a dynamic form so I can't really show you the structure but the other dev in my team said it had to do with their format of dates functions. I'll let you know if there's anything he can have done to fix it. Thank you

Comment: hi, have you found the root couse? I'm having same issue, but very rarely